# MikTex configure dest-names-size for pdflatex

Tags: miktex

When running a large document with pdflatex in MikTex (2.9) I get the error message:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [number of destination names (dest_names_size)=500000].
```

I tried to fix this by means of:

```
pdflatex -dest-names-size=900000
```

But this gave in (`C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log`):

```
2018-04-15 14:15:51,060+0200 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex -dest-names-size=900000 test.tex

    2018-04-15 14:15:51,066+0200 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
    2018-04-15 14:15:51,067+0200 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
    2018-04-15 14:15:51,067+0200 FATAL pdflatex - The command line options could not be processed.
    2018-04-15 14:15:51,067+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: optionError="unknown option"
    2018-04-15 14:15:51,067+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\webapp.cpp
    2018-04-15 14:15:51,067+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 341
    2018-04-15 14:15:51,077+0200 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

In the past I've been able to overcome similar problems with the pool size by means of:

```
pdflatex -pool-size=2000000 test.tex
```

In the MikTex document (https://mirror.cyber-perikarp.eu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/doc/2.9/miktex.pdf) I found a reference to pdfTex (page 103) and on page 79 about adding a value to `pdftex.cfg` by means of:

```
initexmf --edit-config-file pdftex.cfg
```

So I tried:

```
dest_names_size 900000
```

as well as (separately):

```
dest-names-size 900000
dest_names_size = 900000
dest-names-size = 900000
```

but none helped.

So the question now is what should I do to get the configuration right.

Comment: as an alternative to reconfiguring tex, you could look at your macros, do you really need 50000 named destinations in a single document?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Problem here is that it is generated Tex documentation, so it would be hard to change this (in the part it stops it is the source code displayed for an unfortunately very large source file. Other problem I have what is meant with "named destinations", are these e.g. the targets of an hyperref? in case it are hyperref references it is not really possible.

Comment: Try `initexmf --edit-config-file pdflatex` (without .cfg) and add to the file `dest_names_size = 900000`. I have no idea if it works at all and if the format must be recreated then. The default according to the docu is 131072, so it is rather unclear where your 500000 is from.  Aso so many destinations sounds as if something is wrong in your code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer unfortunately didn't help. I also have no idea where the 500000 comes from.

Comment: Sorry as I have no idea how you manage to overflow this I can't reproduce your issue and so can't run tests.

Comment: yes essentially they are the back end targets in the generated pdf, but do you really have 50000 separate places that you link to in the pdf? It would seem likely that you could adjust the macros to make fewer anchors

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks anyway, unfortunately I cannot send the code (propriety), I keep my eyes open maybe I can find another large coded that has similar problems.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I just did a quick count on the Hypertargets and got 55626 lines, for hyperlinks I got 482867

Answer (score 1):

You have made an error in your command line: the log shows:

-dest-names-dize=900000

I think it's:

-dest-names-size=900000

François

Comment: Nice catch, unfortunately this was not the reason of the underlying problem (I did use everywhere else the dest-names-size). When using the ```pdflatex -dest-names-size=900000``` the same error occurs. I've adjusted (manipulated) the original post